# Regex that looks for different characters depending on whether others are found

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm trying to capture each of the following python import statements as distinct matching groups in a regex with JavaScript:

```py
from myapp.foo import SomeReallyGreatClass
from myapp.bar import AnotherClassThatIsNotAsGood, WHAT_A_CONSTANT, SUCH_CONSTANT, \
  YET_ANOTHER_CONSTANT
from myapp.baz import (FirstClassEver, ThisClassDoesNothing, CanYouBelieveThisEvenExists,
  SoManyImports)
```

How would I accomplish this with a JavaScript regex? For the multiline one with a slash, I need the regex to know that if the line ends in a slash it should match up until the next newline that does not come after a slash. For the one with parentheses, it needs to know that if an open parenthesis is found, it would include the subsequent lines until a closing parenthesis is found.

Comment: https://github.com/differentmatt/filbert

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the requirement is to match all the import statements,

try regex: `(^from (?:.*\n)+?(?=^from|$))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5H8iFT/1)

Please note that this is not having 1 match and multiple groups, instead multiple matches with 1 group for each import. With this approach we need not handle `\` or `(` separately